# Add style to all paragraphs after heading CCS

Tags: css

Quiero agregar un margen izquierdo a los encabezados H3 y párrafos asociados con esos encabezados.

El único en el que puedo pensar para los párrafos debajo del H3 es:

`h3 + p { margin-left: 25px; }`

Sin embargo, esto solo se aplica al primer párrafo y quiero que se aplique a todos los párrafos antes del encabezado H2.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?
Adjunto un sitio web con este problema: https://www.ipedd.com/ilicito-administrativo-o-ilicito-penal-una-mirada-desde-la-proteccion-de-la-libre-competencia/